# Inserting multiple information in different table, Mysq, Node.js

Tags: html, mysql, sql, node.js, express

so, i have three tables, user, modules, and an intermediate table user_module, to do an inner join between user and module i have to access thorough user_module

```
"SELECT user.uName, module.moduleName FROM user_module INNER JOIN user ON user.userID = user_module.userID_FK INNER JOIN module ON module.moduleID = user_module.moduleID_FK;",
```

i have a form that allows me to insert the information for the user, and i would like to chose which module a user take. until now i have been putting the information manually with phpmyadmin for the user_module table, the rest f the information for user comes from the node.js code

```
const parsed = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.post("/", parsed, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  connection.query(
    "INSERT INTO user(name,surname,gender,dateOfBirth,email,userName,password) values('" +
      req.body.name1 +
      "','" +
      req.body.surname1 +
      "','" +
      req.body.gender +
      "','" +
      req.body.birtdate +
      "','" +
      req.body.email1 +
      "','" +
      req.body.username1 +
      "','" +
      req.body.password1 +
      "');",
    (err, row, field) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.redirect("/");
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

But how i can take the information from the form, and put the 2 id's in the intermediate table?

```
<form action="/" method="post">
      <p>Name:</p>
      <input type="text" name="name1" /><br />
      <p>Surname:</p>
      <input type="text" name="surname1" /><br />
      <p>Gender:</p>
      <select name="gender">
        <option value="m">Male</option>
        <option value="f">female</option> </select
      ><br />
      <p>course:</p>
      <select name="module">
        <option value="1">Programming</option>
        <option value="2">webApp</option> </select
      ><br />
      <p>Date of Birth:</p>
      <input type="date" name="birtdate" placeholder="select Birth date" />
      <p>Email:</p>
      <input type="email" name="email1" />
      <p>Username:</p>
      <input type="text" name="username1" />
      <p>Password:</p>
      <input type="password" name="password1" /> <br />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: i never worked with `node.js` but i do know EcmaScript (Javascript) but i am pretty sure that code is prone to [(blind) SQL injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blind_SQL_Injection)..

Comment: A manual about using a MySQL in `node.js` seams to be supporting mine statement -> [Escaping query values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of actions you do is really important here:

1) You have to save the user first because you need to have its id. After you have **successfully** saved it, then you need to get its id. Sometimes after successful save some frameworks provide the ID of the saved entity, but you can always get it manually, via a new SQL query to get the id of the user with a specific email.

```
SELECT id from users where email='email_of_the_user_you_just_saved"
```

2) After you have user ID, and you have collected module id from the frontend, then simply make insert into intermediate table user_module.

```
INSERT INTO user_module (user_id, module_id) VALUES (users_id_you_got_from_step_1, module_id_you_got_from_frontend);
```